# GRASS in Ubuntu, python/gui error

Tags: grass-gis, installation, ubuntu, linux, wxpython

Im new to Linux, installed grass from the Ubuntu software centre. When I try to run it I get an error message saying there's an error with wxpython and to install grass gui. I have wxpython3, and setup the repositories from the grass download for Linux page. Then went to install grass-gui but it says multiple libraries are missing. Can anyone help?

Comment: You might try the ubuntugis unstable ppa to get the latest GRASS binaries.